# Unable to convert HTML text into PdfPCell using itextpdf

Tags: java, report, itext, itextpdf, pdfptable

I'm trying to display a **HTML** string in the **PdfPTable** using **itextpdf**.

Here's what I have done:

```
String solution = "<p>some text</p>";
Phrase htmlPhrase = new Phrase(": ", fontNormal10);
StyleSheet styleSheet = new StyleSheet();
styleSheet.loadTagStyle("body", "size", "10pt");
styleSheet.loadTagStyle("p", "size", "10pt");
java.util.List < Element > ie = HTMLWorker.parseToList(new StringReader(solution), styleSheet);
for (Element element: ie) {
    htmlPhrase.add(element);
}
cell = new PdfPCell(htmlPhrase);
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
table.addCell(cell);
```

I still see **HTML tags** in the related cell.

Comment: See the comments of this question asked less only 8 hours before your question was asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533150/itextsharpstyling-related-to-html-page-not-coming-in-generated-pdf

Comment: I have already seen it; did not work for me. By the way I'm using iTextPDF; not ITextSharp.

Comment: I'm the developer of iText. iTextSharp is the C# port of iText. It is maintained by people I hire. I'm sorry that it doesn't work for you. It's a pity you don't explain the problem (otherwise people would do an attempt to answer): http://lowagie.com/doesntwork

Comment: I think it's clear; "did not work" means I still see HTML tags despite using HTMLWorker. The question is clear, how can I display a HTML text into a cell; that's all.